# How to disabled MFA on accouint

Tags: heroku, accessibility, multi-factor-authentication, disable

I lost my device authenticator to entry on my account Heroku, and I can't disable this security, I tried contacting the help center, but the answers I can't view it because I can't log in, my apps will be removed any suggestions?

I want to Disabled MFA authentication on my account to log in with only my password and later I was able again

Comment: This is exactly what MFA is supposed to do. If you can't provide a token, you can't log in. In the future I strongly suggest that you configure an alternate MFA source and / or save your recovery codes.